# Testing for correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, pearson-r

I'm new to statistics. I'm solving a problem where I'm given three sets of data, the measured sizes of the population of rabbits, the drug dose that's been given to each of them and the method of administering the drug (oral or IV). The problem literally states:

**Test whether adding the drug affects the size of the rabbit.**

The way the problem is framed, I'd assume that I should calculate the Pearson's $r$ coefficient and then apply the $t$-test. But I'm confused because there's a categorical component to the problem: there's a difference whether we give a rabbit the oral or IV dose. Should I just ignore the method of dosing and calculate the $r$?

Note that this is a homework problem, so I'm not looking for a complete solution. I just have no idea what the problem asks of me. This isn't something that we have done in class, so I really don't know what to do. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When a problem asks things like "affects" or "improves" or such words, then a good place to start is with regression, rather than correlation. Also, with regression, you can have any kind of independent variable.

If you haven't learned about regression then I am not sure what your professor wants.